Migration Paths for Crypto.SE
We were told in chat that we should open a meta thread to ask for the migration paths. This is this thread.
For everyone not knowing what a migration path is:
Question can be migrated between different sites on the StackExchange Network and usually this can only be done by moderators. So only a mod can migrate a question from SO to Coffee.SE.
This is where the migration paths come into play. They serve as another close reason which will automatically migrate the question to the selected site. These target sites aren't arbitrary though, but rather from a specific subset of all SE sites.
So this question asks for two things (I know this is bad style but should be OK here):

Can we please get migration paths?
Please suggest migration targets as answers (maybe with a nice statistical reasoning?)


The first question is for the SE staff and not for the Crypto.SE community ;)

I'd guess Security.SE and SO are the most needed migration targets.

I think on the first question, we get them once someone requests a specific migration path (e.g., to Security) in a meta question (not sure if it has to be a separate question or if we can have multiple in one question) and it gets enough upvotes and demonstrates enough "need" (whatever that means).

For example, here is a meta question on Security.SE asking for a migration path to Crypto.

@mikeazo, did they get the path yet?

doesn't look like it. I don't have voting privileges on there, so I can check. but usually an SE employee will leave an answer on things like that.

@mikeazo It seems the reverse migration path was added, it's on [tag:status-completed]. Should we make a separate post for this migration path?

@MaartenBodewes it might be worth a shot. Possibly with a link to the Security.SE meta-post.

What you were told in chat by Grace Note was (emphasis by me):

Just make a meta thread demonstrating the need, anyone can do it. We'll then review it and then enable the path if it seems appropriate.

As Abby explains in this Meta post on Data Science (again, emphasis by me):

We add additional migration paths (that is, paths visible to users via the flag or close menu) once there is a demonstrated need for them. Basically, we look at the volume of posts being migrated, and when it starts to create a burden on moderators--who have to handle the flags and migrate the posts manually--we think about adding new paths. 

I'd also like to point you to When should we consider adding a default migration path?, so that you can have a better notion of our process when evaluating the need to add migration paths.

I seem to see questions all the time that should simply be migrated over there -- Service match-up…by hashing service description and session ID?, How to decrypt raw TLS bytes? -- when I click through the flag dialog and see “This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network”, that's a perfectly correct flag, but it doesn't let me select the correct community in the sub-menu, forcing me to go back out and choose a less correct flag.

If you feel there's a need for the path, consider starting a new post to discuss that need with the rest of the community (as opposed to jumping to a feature request), @JamesTheAwesomeDude :)

that's the thing -- it appears that there's already a whole host of threads discussing that need already: Nov 2013, Jul 2015, Aug 2016, Feb 2018, Dec 2018, and this thread. These all range from discussion to requests, all with a consensus that it'd be a good idea, so I'm not clear on why it's not happened yet.

I think it just never made its way to the CM team? Maybe consider flagging the most relevant post(s) to be escalated to the CM team as per this process.
